Auto-unlocking and mounting encrypted bcachefs filesystem on boot. Is there a better way?
I'm currently using a hacky systemd script with hardcoded password to auto-unlock and mount bcachefs filesystem on boot.
Is there a better way to improve security by using a key file perhaps?
I was using key file for LUKS + Btrfs prior to the migration to bcachefs as my OS (openSUSE Slowroll) has full disk encryption.
I could not find anything about key file unlock in the bcachefs documentation or manpage.
# /etc/systemd/system/usbraid.service
[Unit]
Description=Mount encrypted BcacheFS pool
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
Group=root
KeyringMode=shared
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "echo '<password>' | bcachefs mount UUID=21b47fe4-4104-45fb-9e39-9be1cdddcda3 /usbraid/"
ExecStop=/usr/bin/umount /usbraid/
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target

